# Passing parameters to .NET ClickOnce-deployed application from Flex without URL being visible

Tags: .net, apache-flex, actionscript, clickonce, httpservice

I'm passing parameters to a .NET ClickOnce-deployed application via the URL from a Flex application. This is done by simply redirecting the user to http://myDomain/myApplication.application?a=1.

I would like the URL to not be visible in the browser that links to the application.  From what I understand, ClickOnce does not work with POST, so that option's out. .NET folks, is there another option? From ASP.NET, I could have done a simple Server.Transfer to the launching URL.

From a Flex application, I don't know what options I have. NavigateToURL will make the URL visible in the browser. Opening a tiny window with that address will still leave it visible for a second or two.

I tried using an mx:Httpservice component to make a request to that URL, but that didn't work. I'm not sure why. I tried using both the following:

```
<mx:HTTPService id="launcherService" 
                    url="http://myDomain/myApplication.application?a=1">
    var parameters:Object = new Object();
    launcherService.send();
```

and

```
<mx:HTTPService id="launcherService" 
                    url="http://myDomain/myApplication.application">  

var parameters:Object = new Object();
    parameters.a = 1;
    launcherService.send(parameters);
```

I used HTTPWatch and I can see that the HTTP request was made. But the application wasn't deployed. I don't know why. Is there a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HTTPService` is for fetching a url and parsing the retrieved data within the flex application itself. `navigateToUrl` is the normal way to go if you're trying to redirect the user to a URL, but you cannot hide the address bar of the target window with it. To hide the address bar, you need to use javascript. Use [ExternalInterface](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html) to call javascript from your Flex application. The catch is that the pop-up blocker might prevent the pop-up from displaying - you'd have to ask user to allow pop-ups from your site.

Try calling

```
ExternalInterface.call("window.open('" + url + "', '_blank', 'menubar=0,location=0,toolbar=0'"));
```